# Vue component works locally but not on server

Tags: laravel, vue-component

Everything works fine on local server. Two Vue components, both Algoliaserach, like this:

```
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';
Vue.use(InstantSearch);

Vue.component('algolia-instantsearch', require('./components/InstantSearch.vue'));
Vue.component('algolia-booksearch', require('./components/BookSearch.vue'));


var app = new Vue({
    components: {InstantSearch},
});

var bookshelf = new Vue({
    components: {BookSearch},
});
```

As I said, works great on local, but once pushed to server, I get this error:

```
<algolia-booksearch> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Can u provide detail aboit your local environement, and server?

Comment: local laravel install, valet, npm run production to mix it all up. digital ocean

Comment: Share vue routes if you are using ?